# How can I create a simple index.html file which lists all files/directories?

Tags: html, webserver

We use a web server that does not allow directory listing.

There is a specific directory I would like to allow listing of.

How can make a simple HTML file that will contain the contents of this directory?

Comment: What language do you have ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either:
Write a server-side script page like PHP, JSP, ASP.net etc to generate this HTML dynamically

or

Setup the web-server that you are using (e.g. Apache) to do exactly that automatically for directories that doesn't contain welcome-page (e.g. index.html)

**Specifically in apache read more here:
Edit the  httpd.conf:
http://justlinux.com/forum/showthread.php?s=&postid=502789#post502789 (updated link: https://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?94230-Make-apache-list-directory-contents&highlight=502789)**

or add the autoindex mod:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Comment: The apache server is out of my control. `.htaccess` is disabled. I'm a real newbie to this, so a simple working example would be appreciated.

Comment: does your apache support PHP? you must use apache that supports server-side scriptwriting otherwise it's impossible..

Comment: add some php file like hello.php, edit this file: "<?php  Print "Hello, World!";?> " , try to access it from the client http://server/hello.php and see what you get..

Comment: @MrOhad This works. So what should I pout in the HTML to allow listing?

Comment: You can have apache on your local machine, to generate the index files,  then use `wget` or `curl` to download the page generated.  Apache Fancy Directory Listings allow file descriptions, changing the icons for file types, and add a header and/or footer HTML.  This is an example a very fancy Apache directory listing, captured and served on gitlab...  https://antofthy.gitlab.io/info/perl/

Answer (score 155):

There are enough valid reasons to explicitly disable automatic directory indexes in apache or other web servers. Or, for example, you might only want to include certain file types in the index. In these cases you might still want to have a statically generated **index.html** file in specific folders.

### `tree`

[**tree**](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/tree.1.html) is a minimalistic utility that is available on most unix-like systems (ubuntu/debian: `sudo apt install tree`, mac: `brew install tree`, windows: [zip](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tree.htm)).

`tree` can generate plain text, XML (`-X`), JSON (`-J`) and HTML (`-H`) output.

Generate an HTML directory index one level deep, skip, ie `-I`gnore the generated `index.html` file itself, include sizes (`-s`) and timestamps (`-D`):

```bash
tree -H '.' -L 1 --noreport --dirsfirst -T 'Downloads' -s -D --charset utf-8 -I "index.html" -o index.html
```

Include only specific file types that match a glob pattern, e.g. `*.zip` and `*.gz` files, dirs first, include size and timestamps with a custom date format:

```bash
tree -H '.' \
    -L 1 \
    --noreport \
    --houtro ""
    --dirsfirst \
    --charset utf-8 \
    --ignore-case \
    --timefmt '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M' \
    -I "index.html" \
    -T 'Downloads' \
    -s -D \
    -P "*.zip|*.gz" \
    -o index.html
```

> <sup>`-H '.'` enable HTML mode and set base href, can be relative e.g. `.` or absolute e.g. `/files`. 
>
> `-L 1` limit to current directory only 
>
> `--noreport` do not include the summary at the end 
>
> `--houtro ""` suppress the credits at the end by setting an empty outro file name 
>
> `--dirsfirst` put directories first 
>
> `--charset utf-8` ensure UTF-8 charset 
>
> `--ignore-case` make the `-I` and `-P` options case insensitive 
>
> `--timefmt '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M'` set date format (see `man strftime` in your terminal for details [*](https://strftime.org/)). 
>
> `-I "index.html"` **I**gnore, i.e. do not include the generated `index.html` file in the listing 
>
> `-P "*.zip|*.gz"` filter by glob **P**attern, e.g. only include zip/gz files 
>
> `-T` set custom **T**itle (has no effect if `--hintro` (set custom intro file) is defined) 
>
> `-s` include file **S**izes 
>
> `-D` include modified **d**ates 
>
> `-o index.html` write to file (stdout by default)</sup>

> If you don't want any title at all you can suppress the header block with `--hintro ""` which will set an empty include file for the intro.

For all supported options see `tree --help` or **[`man tree`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree)** in a shell.

### Recursively create index.html files in subdirectories

Combined with gnu `find` you can recursively create index files in a subtree e.g. with:

```bash
find . -type d -print -exec sh -c 'tree "$0" \
    -H "." \
    -L 1 \
    --noreport \
    --houtro ""
    --dirsfirst \
    --charset utf-8 \
    -I "index.html" \
    -T "Custom Title" \
    --ignore-case \
    --timefmt "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M" \
    -s \
    -D \
    -o "$0/index.html"' {} \;
```

### Generator script with recursive traversal

I needed an index generator which I could style the way I want, so ended up writing [**this script**](https://gist.github.com/glowinthedark/625eb4caeca12c5aa52778a3b4b0adb4) (python 3) which in addition to having customisable styling can also recursively generate an `index.html` file in all the nested subdirectories (with the `--recursive` or `-r` flag). The styling borrows heavily from caddyserver's `file-server` module <sup>[*](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/blob/master/modules/caddyhttp/fileserver/browse.html)</sup>. It includes last modified time and is responsive in mobile viewports.

*Update*: [A newer version of the script linked above](https://github.com/glowinthedark/index-html-generator/) that generates friendly SVG icons for a few dozens of file types (makes slightly bigger index.html files).

Comment: excellent solution!!! if you want to omit directories in your `index.html` file, add `--prune` to the `tree` command

Comment: Inspired by your script, I wrote [https://github.com/yencarnacion/html4tree](https://github.com/yencarnacion/html4tree).  html4tree is written in Kotlin.

Comment: @ccpizza, the link to the script is broken.

Comment: This is a great solution for deploying a site to place like GitLab Pages which only allows static web content (i.e. no php) and also does not allow the use of .htaccess.

Comment: Thank you for the script! Worked perfectly when I needed a quick hack. All hail SO.

Comment: sadly on Windows it doesn't seem to support the options including limiting to file types that make it effective :/

Comment: Tree works for me in an AWS Amazon website if I don't produce index.html but dircontent.html and link to that.

Comment: If you're running this a second time, you might want to add `-I "index.html"` to not include the index.html file itself.

Comment: Brilliant! Simple, elegant, to-the-point.

Answer (score 42):

For me PHP is the easiest way to do it:

```
<?php
echo "Here are our files";
$path = ".";
$dh = opendir($path);
$i=1;
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "index.php" && $file != ".htaccess" && $file != "error_log" && $file != "cgi-bin") {
        echo "<a href='$path/$file'>$file</a><br /><br />";
        $i++;
    }
}
closedir($dh);
?>
```

Place this in your directory and set where you want it to search on the $path. The first if statement will hide your php file and .htaccess and the error log. It will then display the output with a link. This is very simple code and easy to edit.

Comment: This has multiple stored XSS vulnerabilities: filenames can contain quotes and < >, etc.

Comment: When I try this on AWS, the $file</a><br />;$i++;}}closedir($dh);?> are the result with the spacing as specified by the <br />

Answer (score 12):

There's a free php script made by Celeron Dude that can do this called Celeron Dude Indexer 2. It doesn't require `.htaccess` The source code is easy to understand and provides a good starting point.

Here's a download link: https://gitlab.com/desbest/celeron-dude-indexer/

[image: celeron dude indexer]

Answer (score 7):

Did you try to allow it for this directory via .htaccess?

```
Options +Indexes
```

I use this for some of my directories where directory listing is disabled by my provider

Comment: That was my first choice, but the apache server is out of my control and it seems `.htaccess` is disabled. I get `Internal Server Error` when adding such `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a staging server that has directory listing enabled, then you can copy the `index.html` to the production server.

For example:

```sh
wget https://staging/dir/index.html

# do any additional processing on index.html

scp index.html prod/dir
```

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with pure HTML.

However if you have access to PHP on the Apache server (you tagged the post "apache") it can be done easilly - [se the PHP glob function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). If not - you might try Server Side Include - it's an Apache thing, and I don't know much about it.

Comment: I've never wrote PHP. If you could give a working example for an HTML I can put in my dir - it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If you have `node` then you can use `fs` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search) to get all the files:

```
const { resolve } = require('path'),
  { readdir } = require('fs').promises;

async function getFiles(dir) {
  const dirents = await readdir(dir, { withFileTypes: true });
  const files = await Promise.all(dirents.map((dirent) => {
    const res = resolve(dir, dirent.name);
    return dirent.isDirectory() ? getFiles(res) : res;
  }));
  return Array.prototype.concat(...files);
}
```

And you might use that like this:

```
const directory = "./Documents/";
  
getFiles(directory).then(results => {
  const html = `<ul>` +
  results.map(fileOrDirectory => `<li>${fileOrDirectory}</li>`).join('\n') +
  `</ul>`;

  process.stdout.write(html);
  // or you could use something like fs.writeFile to write the file directly
});
```

You could call it at the command-line with something like this:

```
$ node thatScript.js > index.html
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to use a local apache web server to generate HTML index files.

- Have a local apache web server with 'fancy indexes' enabled as you want them.  This includes having headers and footers (readme file) on a per directory basis.
- Download the missing apache index files from localhost and save them
- Upload the changes to the remote static web server
- Remove the generated index files.

This works very well, and means I can test and check any changes on the local apcahe webserver, before I generate listings and uploading the files.  In fact my indexes were designed to use apache fancy indexing LONG before I was force to switch to a static web server, so I did not have to re-designed them for a different index generator.

The script to do it was actually VERY simple and written in plain shell.

If you like to see the uploaded result...
Visit my "Tower of Computational Sorcery"...
https://antofthy.gitlab.io/info/

Answer (score -1):

You can't directly create an HTML file to list the contents of a directory if directory listing is disabled on the web server. However, you can create a server-side script (like PHP, Python, or Node.js) to generate a dynamic HTML page that lists the contents of the directory.

Here's an example using PHP:

```
    <?php
    // Set the directory you want to list
    $directory = './specific_directory/';
    
    // Get all files in the directory
    $files = scandir($directory);
    
    // Remove "." and ".." from the list
    $files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..'));
    
    // Output HTML
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Directory Listing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Directory Listing</h1>
        <ul>';
    
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . $directory . $file . '">' . $file . '</a></li>';
    }
    
    echo '</ul>
    </body>
    </html>';

?>
```

Save this PHP code in a file with a .php extension (e.g., directory_listing.php) and upload it to your server in a directory where PHP is enabled. Then, you can access this file via a web browser, and it will dynamically list the contents of the specified directory.

Make sure to replace './specific_directory/' with the path to the directory you want to list. Additionally, ensure that you have proper permissions set up for the directory and that you're aware of the security implications of listing directory contents on a public-facing website.