# Is there wildcard mechanism for listing sources in node-gyp

Tags: node-gyp

I'm writing `binding.gyp` file for my new node.js module. I have all my source files under `src/` subdirectory. I would like to use all of them while building the module. Instead of modifying binding.gyp each time I add a new cpp file, I would like to list all cpp files through some wildcard mechanism. Does node-gyp support that? Something like following (which doesn't work

```
{
  'targets' : [
      {
          'target_name' : 'mymod',
          'sources' : 'src/*.cpp'
      }
   ]
}
```

I looked at https://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/InputFormatReference , but didn't find anything readily useful.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Figured it out

```
{
  'targets' : [
      {
          'target_name' : 'mymod',
          'sources' : [ '<!@(ls -1 src/*.cpp)' ],
      }
   ]
}
```

Check out [this link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp/+/md-pages/docs/InputFormatReference.md#Command-Expansions)

**Update**

The solution above is not portable across platforms. Here's a portable version:

```
{
  'targets' : [
      {
          'target_name' : 'mymod',
          'sources' : [  "<!@(node -p \"require('fs').readdirSync('./src').map(f=>'src/'+f).join(' ')\")" ],
      }
   ]
}
```

Essentially it replaces the platform specific directory listing command (`ls`), by Javascript code that uses node's `fs` module to list the directory contents.

Answer (score 0):

An even more portable version (that doesn't depend on node, but rather python):

```
"<!@(python -c \"import os; print '\n'.join(['%s' % x for x in os.listdir('.') if x[-3:] == '.cc' and 'test' not in x])\")"
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter specific file extensions like `cpp` and to support also pre-compiled `libraries` `.a` files, I have slightly modified the accepted solution to be:

```
'sources': [
        'jamspell.cpp',
        "<!@(node -p \"require('fs').readdirSync('./src').filter(f=>f.endsWith('.cpp')).map(f=>'src/'+f).join(' ')\")",
        "<!@(node -p \"require('fs').readdirSync('./src/jamspell').filter(f=>f.endsWith('.cpp')).map(f=>'src/jamspell/'+f).join(' ')\")"
        ],
        'include_dirs': [
            "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
        ],
        'libraries': [
          "<!@(node -p \"require('fs').readdirSync('./lib/contrib').filter(f=>f.endsWith('.a')).map(f=>'lib/contrib/'+f).join(' ')\")"
        ],
        'dependencies': [
            "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to include all sub files and folders within a certain folder (defined at end of line, here as "sources"):

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [ 
            "<!@(node -p \"var fs=require('fs'),path=require('path'),walk=function(r){let t,e=[],n=null;try{t=fs.readdirSync(r)}catch(r){n=r.toString()}if(n)return n;var a=0;return function n(){var i=t[a++];if(!i)return e;let u=path.resolve(r,i);i=r+'/'+i;let c=fs.statSync(u);if(c&&c.isDirectory()){let r=walk(i);return e=e.concat(r),n()}return e.push(i),n()}()};walk('./sources').join(' ');\")"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

(based off, but not exactly: [node.js fs.readdir recursive directory search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search/60946635#60946635))

Answer (score 0):

Recursive script for windows, might work for linux/macos too.

```
"sources": [
  "<!@(node sources.js)"
],
```

**sources.js**

```js
const { resolve, relative } = require('path');
const { readdir } = require('fs').promises;

async function getFiles(dir) {
  const dirents = await readdir(dir, { withFileTypes: true });
  const files = await Promise.all(
    dirents.map(dirent => {
      const res = resolve(dir, dirent.name);
      return dirent.isDirectory() ? getFiles(res) : res;
    }),
  );
  return Array.prototype.concat(...files);
}

(async () => {
  const files = (await getFiles(resolve(__dirname)))
    .filter(
      v =>
        v.endsWith('.cpp') ||
        v.endsWith('.h') ||
        v.endsWith('.hpp') ||
        v.endsWith('.cc') ||
        v.endsWith('.c'),
    )
    .map(v => relative(__dirname, v))
    .map(v => v.replace(/\\/g, '/')) // remove on mac/linux
    .join(' ');
  console.log(files);
  return files;
})();
```