# node-gyp: run binding.gyp in all subdirectories

Tags: node.js, recursion, compilation, native, node-gyp

I'm developing a big [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) project which also includes several native libraries.
To use these libraries in JavaScript I'm compiling them to node addons (`.node`) using [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp).

I'd like to run [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) once from the root directory to compile all the available `binding.gyp` recursively (in all the subdirectories).

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GYP allows to set a list of dependencies for a target. You can create a target of `type: none` in the top-level `bindings.gyp` and list there dependencies from subdirectories:

```
{
    'targets': [
        {
            'target_name': 'build_all',
            'type': 'none',
            'dependencies': ['subdir1/bindings.gyp:*', 'subdir/subdir2/bindings.gyp:*'],
            # or generate dependencies list with a command expansion
            'dependencies': ['<!@(find -mindepth 2 -name binding.gyp | sed -e s/$/:*/)'],
        }
    ]
}
```

This will compile all the dependencies and put them into `build/` directory in the root.
For putting each addon in its corresponding directory, add a `postbuild` target inside the addon's `binding.gyp`:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "my-target",
      "sources": [ "example.cpp" ]      
    },      
    {
      "target_name": "action_after_build",
      "type": "none",
      "dependencies": [ "my-target" ],
      "copies": [
        {
          "files": [ "<(PRODUCT_DIR)/my-target.node" ],
          "destination": "."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This way every time I add a new native module I'll have to update this bindings.gyp index.

Comment: GYP also can expand a command, so you can combine approaches from both answers. But you will need to re-generate build files with `node-gyp rebuild` after adding new native module.

Comment: I intend to run `node-gyp rebuild` anyways (in fact you can see that in my solution). But I'm not sure I got your point... What do you mean by GYP also can expand a command?

Comment: See (Command Expansions)[https://gyp.gsrc.io/docs/InputFormatReference.md#Command-Expansions] in GYP reference. GYP will execute a shell command on `!(...)` or `!@(..)` variable expansion.

But GYP is running only on configure stage, i.e. `node-gyp configure` or `node-gyp rebuild`

Comment: I see... so you propose put `"find ./app/* -name binding.gyp"` inside a root `gyp` file instead of `package.json` scripts? Why do you think it is a better approach?

Comment: I don't know which is the better approach, it's up to you. I just suggest another possible way.

Comment: I understand. I think I'll accept your answer, as it integrates in a more seamless way into the build process. In fact, `node-gyp rebuild` is a [default command in install script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) (given there is a `bindings.gyp` file in the root directory). And it is [mentioned](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) in best practices to avoid the use of `install` and use `gyp` file instead.

Comment: For some reason the expansion won't work when there are several `binding.gyp` files in the sub directories... It works fine when there is only one, but when there are two or more I get this error    

`gyp: native\node-addon\binding.gyp
\native\node-addon-Copy\binding.gyp not found`

Comment: Figured out what is the problem: when you use list expansion, something like `<@(var)blah`, the `blah` thing will be only attached to the last entry in the list. Therefore the solution you proposed won't work.

Comment: Yes, I have discovered the same. I always thought that expansion is being applied to each list item. Anyway there is a workaround: to generate list items with required suffix `:*`, like `find -mindepth 2  -name binding.gyp | sed -e s/$/:*/`

I also added `-mindepth 2` to exclude the top-level `binding.gyp` from the result list

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking into the `sed` too. Solves the problem.

Comment: Obviously this won't work on Windows. A kind of `find` analogue is `dir /b/s` there, so to append `:*` suffix such one-line can be used: `for /f %i in ('dir /s/b binding.gyp') do @echo %i:*` but I haven't tested it with GYP

Comment: Correct. Although it won't be an issue if one uses bash on Windows (gitbash or something).
There's still another issue though... If you build a common target (top level `binding.gyp`) it puts all the binaries inside the top level build `directory`. I'd like each of the binaries to be placed in its corresponding directory (alongside the corresponding `binding.gyp`)

Comment: Meanwhile the only solution I found for this one is adding a copy step in each child `binding.gyp`. I'll suggest and edit for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any option to do this with just `node-gyp`, but one of the possible solutions is doing this in a script.
For example, adding the following to the `package.json` in the root folder:

```
 "scripts": {
    "install": "find ./app/* -name binding.gyp -execdir node-gyp rebuild ;"
 }
```

This will cause all the native addons to compile when running `npm install` in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the other answers which seems to work so far (without ever having to update binding.gyp):

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [ 
            "<!@(node -p \"var fs=require('fs'),path=require('path'),walk=function(r){let t,e=[],n=null;try{t=fs.readdirSync(r)}catch(r){n=r.toString()}if(n)return n;var a=0;return function n(){var i=t[a++];if(!i)return e;let u=path.resolve(r,i);i=r+'/'+i;let c=fs.statSync(u);if(c&&c.isDirectory()){let r=walk(i);return e=e.concat(r),n()}return e.push(i),n()}()};walk('./sources').join(' ');\")"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60947528/2016831)