# Recursion inside Async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion

In the following code InsertIntoDB is a recursive function. Problem is after one one call to InsertIntoDB it executes mainFn. I want to execute mainFn after InsertIntoDB is completely over.

This is my code:

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        insertIntoDB(obj);
        callback();
    },
    function(callback) {
        mainFn();
        callback();
    }
]);
```

Comment: For what I was looking for (cascading tree deletion) this link was useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you use async waterfall instead

https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall