# Gulp - Target all files in a folder and its subfolders

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'd like to be able to add a `watch` task in `gulp` to all of the `js` files in the `frontend/js` and any other js files below

```
 gulp.watch('./frontend/js/**/*.js', ['browserify']);
```

This will only target `js` files one folder deep

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's supposed to match any number of subdirectories:

> `**` If a "globstar" is alone in a path portion, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches. It does not crawl symlinked directories.

https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

Do you have symlinked directories in there?

## Symlinks

I don't think you'll get gulp to natively traverse your symlinked directories. I recommend you take a look at [node.js fs.readdir recursive directory search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search) and see if any of those solutions can be applied to your use case. Nothing in the question or answers specifically addresses symlinks, so I don't know if there's a solution for you there or not. If you can get an array of dereferenced pathnames using one of those solutions, then you can just pass the array to `gulp.src()`.

Comment: I actually do have smylinks as it happens. Good show old chap

Comment: @KellyJAndrews Other than I can't yet target all the files and the files in their subfolders :) So for me nothing has been answered yet

Comment: Are all of your sub-folders symlinked?

Comment: The entire js folder is ;)

Comment: @Jamie Hutber see Symlinks section of updated answer.

Comment: @Jamie Hutber, are you saying `js` is a symlink to a folder, and that contents of that folder are not symlinks?

Answer (score 6):

I just did some testing - and this actually works just fine for me.

I currently have the following structure -

```
--apps
  --scripts
  ----test.js
  ----test-folder
  ------test2.js
  ------test-folder-deep
  --------test3.js
  --myApp
  ----scripts-symlinked (symlinked to apps/scripts)
  ----gulpfile.js
```

I set up my symlink folder (on Mac - from 'myApp' folder) using:

```
ln -s /Users/kandrews/apps/scripts ./scripts-symlinked
```

In my `gulpfile.js` I have the following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint');

gulp.task('jshint', function () {
    gulp.src('./scripts-symlinked/**/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./scripts-symlinked/**/*.js', ['jshint']);
});
```

Works perfectly. I also tried this in a sub directory as well ('scripts/symlinked-scripts') and was successful as well.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood @Jamie Hutber's folder structure. I thought the contents of the `js` folder were symlinks, not `js` itself. But if that's the case, then based on your results I don't know why their original glob wouldn't have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s not worth doing difficult:

```
gulp.watch('./frontend/js/', ['browserify']);
```