# SASS Gulp-Task: Summarize Files inside Subfolder

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

can everyone help me to improve my `sass` gulptask? I want to summarize `.scss` files inside subfolders....
For example: Inside my `sass-folder` i have a subfolder `home` with all `.scss-files` for the homepage. I want to summarize all files inside the home-folder and compiled these files to `/dist/assets/css/home/style.min.css`

This case doesn't work with my gulptask, it ignore my subfolders. What do I need to change to make it work?

```js
gulp.task('sass', done => {
    gulp.src(src + 'assets/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(postcss([
            tailwindcss(src + 'tailwind.config.js'),
        ], { syntax: require('postcss-scss') }))
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(concat('style'))
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['node_modules']
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(
            purgecss({
                content: [src + '**/*.html'],
                extractors: [
                    {
                      extractor: TailwindExtractor,
                      extensions: ["html"]
                    }
                ]
            })
        )
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist + 'assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    done();
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526891/gulp-target-all-files-in-a-folder-and-its-subfolders

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
gulp.src(src + 'assets/sass/**/*.scss')
```