# What does "!--" do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, decrement, prefix-operator, not-operator

I have this piece of code (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5827895/5665799)):

```
var walk = function(dir, done) {
    var results = [];

    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        var pending = list.length;

        if (!pending) 
            return done(null, results);

        list.forEach(function(file) {
            file = path.resolve(dir, file);
            fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
                if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                    walk(file, function(err, res) {
                        results = results.concat(res);

                        if (!--pending)
                            done(null, results);
                    });
                } else {
                    results.push(file);

                    if (!--pending) 
                        done(null, results);
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

I'm trying to follow it, and I think I understand everything except for near the end where it says `!--pending`. In this context, what does that command do?

Edit: I appreciate all the further comments, but the question has been answered many times. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Could you explain this code, i don't understand why check `if (!--pending) done(null, results);`?

Comment: This reminds me [What is the name of the `-->` operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/447156)

Comment: Note that the use case here can be trivially solved with promises instead of inventing our own synchronization mechanism.  This function doesn't do error handling correctly either. This is why you shouldn't roll your own concurrency unless you have a good reason.

Answer (score 543, accepted):

`!` inverts a value, and gives you the opposite boolean:

```
!true == false
!false == true
!1 == false
!0 == true
```

`--[value]` subtracts one (1) from a number, and then returns that number to be worked with:

```
var a = 1, b = 2;
--a == 0
--b == 1
```

So, `!--pending` subtracts one from pending, and then returns the opposite of its truthy/falsy value (whether or not it's `0`).

```
pending = 2; !--pending == false 
pending = 1; !--pending == true
pending = 0; !--pending == false
```

And yes, follow the ProTip.  This may be a common idiom in other programming languages, but for most declarative JavaScript programming this looks quite alien.

Answer (score 152):

That's not a special operator, it's 2 standard operators one after the other:

1. A prefix decrement (`--`)
2. A logical not (`!`)

This causes `pending` to be decremented and then tested to see if it's zero.

Answer (score 109):

A number of answers describes *what* this command does, but not *why* it is done that way here.

I come from the C world, and I read `!--pending` as "count down `pending` and check if it is zero" without really thinking about it.  It is an idiom that I think programmers in similar languages should know.

The function uses `readdir` to get a list of files and subdirectories, which I will collectively call "entries".

The variable `pending` keeps track of how many of these remains to be processed. It starts out as the length of the list, and counts downward towards zero as each entry is processed.

These entries may be processed out of order, which is why it is necessary to count down rather than just using a simple loop.  When *all* the entries have been processed the callback `done` is called to notify the original caller of this fact.

In the first call to `done` is prepended with `return`, not because we want to return a value, but simply to make the function stop executing at that point.  It would have been cleaner code to drop the `return` and put the alternative in an `else`.

Answer (score 36):

It's a shorthand.

`!` is "not".

`--` decrements a value.

So `!--` checks if the value obtained from negating the result of decrementing a value is false.

Try this:

```
var x = 2;
console.log(!--x);
console.log(!--x);
```

The first is false, since the value of x is 1, the second is true, since the value of x is 0.

Side note:
`!x--` would check if x is false first, and then decrement it.

Comment: I think you meant to say "`!--` returns the negation of the result of decrementing a value."  Only outside code, such as `console.log()`, checks if its contents are truthy.

Answer (score 31):

`!` is the JavaScript [NOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz722703(v=vs.94).aspx) operator

`--` is a pre-decrement operator. So,

```
x = 1;
if (!x) // false
if (!--x) // becomes 0 and then uses the NOT operator,
          // which makes the condition to be true
```

Answer (score 24):

```
if(!--pending)
```

means

```
if(0 == --pending)
```

means

```
pending = pending - 1;
if(0 == pending)
```

Answer (score 13):

It's the not operator followed by the in-place pre-decrementer.

So if `pending` was an integer with a value of 1:

```
val = 1;
--val; // val is 0 here
!val // evaluates to true
```

Answer (score 13):

## Explanation

This is 2 operators, a `!` and a `--`

```
!--x
```

So, the `--` decrements x by 1, then the `!` returns true if x is now 0 (or NaN...), false if it isn't. You might read this idiom something like "we decrement x and if that makes it zero..."

If you wanted to make it more readable, you can:

```
var x = 1
x = x - 1   
if(!x){ //=> true
    console.log("I understand `!--` now!") 
}
x //=> 0
```

## Try it out:

```js
/* This is an example of the above, you can read this, but it is not needed for !-- */function interactive(a){$("span.code").keydown(function(e){if(13==(e.keyCode||e.which)){var t=$(this);t.clone().html("code").insertAfter(t.next().next()).show().focus().after(template.clone().removeClass("result-template").show()).next().after("<br>"),interactive(),e.preventDefault()}}).keyup(function(e){13!=(e.keyCode||e.which)&&run()})}var template=$(".result-template").hide(),code=$("span.code");code.attr("contenteditable","true").each(function(e,t){template.clone().removeClass("result-template").insertAfter(t)}),interactive(),$.fn.reduce=[].reduce;function run(){var b=!1,context={};$("span.code").each(function(){var a=$(this),res=a.next().show().removeClass("error");try{with(context)res.html(b?"":"  //=> "+eval(a.text()))}catch(e){b=e,res.html("  Error: "+b.message).addClass("error")}})};run();
```

```css
/* This is an example of the above, you can read this, but it is not needed for !-- */span.result.error{display:block;color:red}.code{min-width:10px}body{font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif}
```

```html
<!-- This is an example of the above, you can read this, but it is not needed for `!--` --><span class="result result-template"> //=> unknown </span> <h2>Edit This Code:</h2><code><span class="code">x = 1</span><br><span class="code">!--x</span><br><span class="code"> x </span><br></code> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle (Try Out Code)](https://jsfiddle.net/q19akbt7/10/)

Answer (score 11):

It merely decreases `pending` by one and obtains its logical complement (negation). The logical complement of any number different than 0 is `false`, for 0 it is `true`.

Answer (score 8):

The real problem here is the lack of a space between the two operators `!` and `--`.

I don't know why people get it in their heads that you can't ever use a space after the `!` operator. I think it comes from rigid application of mechanical whitespace rules instead of common sense. Just about every coding standard I've seen prohibits spaces after all unary operators, but why?

If there were ever a case where you clearly *need* that space, this is one.

Consider this bit of code:

```
if (!--pending)
    done(null, results);
```

Not only are `!` and `--` mashed together, you've got that `(` slammed against them too. No wonder it's hard to tell what is connected to what.

A bit more whitespace makes the code much more clear:

```
if( ! --pending )
    done( null, results );
```

Sure, if you're used to mechanical rules like "no space inside parens" and "no space after a unary operator", this may seem a bit foreign.

But look at how the extra whitespace groups and separates the various parts of the `if` statement and expression: You've got `--pending`, so the `--` is clearly its own operator and is tied closely to `pending`. (It decrements `pending` and returns the decremented result.) Then you've got the `!` separated from that so it's obviously a distinct operator, negating the result. Finally, you've got `if(` and `)` surrounding the whole expression to make it an `if` statement.

And yes, I removed the space between `if` and `(`, because the `(` *belongs* to the `if`. This `(` isn't part of some kind of `(!--` syntax as it appears to be in the original, the `(` if part of the syntax of the `if` statement itself.

The whitespace here serves to communicate the *meaning*, instead of following some mechanical coding standard.

Comment: The whitespaced version is more readable to me.  When I first saw the question I assumed `!--` was some javascript operator I did not know.  Why not use parentheses to make it even more explicit? `if(!(--pending))`

Comment: No style guides I am aware of prohibit using `++` or `--`, but many **do** prohibit using non-essential spaces such as after the `!` prefix operator, and non-essential parentheses.

Comment: Whitespace after unary operators is discouraged because it separates it from the expression it operates on. You'd want it to be read together...at least imho