# What is the difference between '+=' and '=+'?

Tags: python, operators

I have a simple piece of code that prints out the integers 1-10:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    print(i)
```

Then if you just change one operator around on line 3, it prints out an infinite amount of 1 integers (which I understand why it does that).

Why isn't a syntax error occurring when running this second program? Wouldn't it call a syntax error in the event of an assignment operator being followed by an addition operator?

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i =+ 1
    print(i)
```

Comment: `i =+ 1` is the same thing as `i = 1`. `+` is the unary operator here.

Comment: See the [language reference on unary expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-u_expr)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`i+=1` is the same as `i=i+1`, whereas
`i=+1` just means `i=(+1)`.

Comment: OP seems to understand that. The question was, why `+1` is not illegal syntax.

Comment: @tobias_k The question *OP actually had* was a duplicate. However, the question *in the title* - which is a perfectly reasonable separate question to have - is addressed by this answer. This is not a great situation, and it shows the weakness of Stack Overflow being powered primarily by questions that OP actually wants answered, rather than by questions that people notice are missing from the "library".

Answer (score 7):

`i =+ 1` is the same as `i = +1`, or `i = 1`.

Answer (score 7):

`x=+1` is treated as:  `x=(+1)` 
while `x+=1` is treated as: `x=x+1`

There are binary operators which operates on their left-handside operand and their right-hand side operand (e.g. * multiplication).

And there are unary operators which takes only right-hand side operand (e.g. ~/! negation).
There are operators which can be unary and binary.

The plus sign in python can be used also as right-hand side operator **just as minus.**

Python Docs:

> The unary - (minus) operator yields the negation of its numeric
> argument.
>
> The unary + (plus) operator yields its numeric argument unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

Tokenizers don't typically require spaces unless it's necessary to disambiguate (e.g. you need a space, or punctuation of some form between a variable name and a language keyword so the keyword can be recognized).

Thus, `x=+y`, `x =+ y` and `x = +y` are all equivalent, in all cases invoking the unary `+` operator on `y` and assigning to `x`. The unary plus operator isn't commonly used, but just because it's uncommon doesn't mean it's not recognized and accepted.

For comparison, the `-->` "operator" in C/C++ etc. is [another example where humans looking for spaces and tokenizers ignoring them causes confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator-in-c).

Comment: `!--` has also been the source of some confusion in [javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34323527/1547004)

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax error because the expression `i =+ 1` is the same as `i = (+1)` and `+1` is perfectly legitimate. It is a unary operator, not the addition operator.