# Simple python program ran into infinite loop

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I am trying to make a simple XOR program. Once I finished checking my syntax, I ran my program and ran into an infinite loop. I can't find my error. Help?

```
def disencode(n):
    seconde = raw_input("Input_Second_String")
    y = len(n)
    x = 0
    while x < y:
        if n[x] == seconde[x]:
            print 0
        else:
            print 1
        x =+1
disencode(raw_input("Input_First_String"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x=+1` should be `x += 1`, as with your current code, you never increment x,
as x =+ 1 is the same thing as x = 1.

You're effectively setting x as 1, never increasing it, and asking the loop to run while x < y, which is infinite.

[See here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643927/the-difference-between-and)

Answer (score 0):

use `x += 1` for incrementing `x` instead of `x =+1`