# How to find sum of a for loop in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Please check my code here:
Sample url: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html 
Sum of the digits found in following url should be (2553).
I have to tried to sum up using several techs but can't find the correct one use the url provided at the top of the code. I need to sum up the strings numbers.

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

# To read the file from the url
url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# To search for specific area of the file
tags = soup('span')
#print(tags)
sum = 0

# Filters your search further and prints the specific part as                     
#string
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.contents[0])
    #ChangeToInt = int(tag.contents[0])
    #sum =+ ChangeToInt
    #print(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

a few pointers, `sum` is a python builtin method for summing up lists of numbers so best not to use it as a variable name. also the syntax for adding to a variable is `+=` but in your code you have `=+`. Your code works with just a change to that syntax ( i have also updated the variable name from sum to total and print only the total after the loop.

```
total = 0
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.contents[0])
    ChangeToInt = int(tag.contents[0])
    total += ChangeToInt
print(total)
```

Alternatively you could write this using pythons sum method and a list comprehension to generate the numbers.

```
total = sum([int(tag.contents[0]) for tag in tags])
print(total)
```

additionally you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643927/the-difference-between-and) for the differnece between `+=` and `=+`

Comment: Yes I got the answer, but it comes likes this
2418
2439
2458
2476
2494
2508
2520
2532
2541
2548
2551
2553 

I wan't just single sum 2553.

Comment: because in your code you are having your print statement inside the for loop so it will print every time it adds anything to the total. you should remove the print statement from inside the for loop and only print the total after the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You simply have your increment syntax wrong:

```
sum =+ ChangeToInt
```

should instead be:

```
sum += ChangeToInt
```

Your code worked just fine for me after I fixed that.

Comment: Yes I got the answer, but it comes likes this
2418
2439
2458
2476
2494
2508
2520
2532
2541
2548
2551
2553 

I wan't just single sum 2553.