# Add up numbers - that can be printed - in Python

Tags: python, list, count

I'm struggling with what seems to be a simple case.
I got to the point where I can search for specific input and I let the program print how many times the given input is within each element of the list.

So take for instance the following list:

```
title = ['hello 2017', 'hello 2019', 'bye 2017']
```

My (very simple) code:

```
for s in title:
    count = s.count('2017')
    print(count)
```

Ouput:

```
1
0
1
```

I tried to replace print(count) with the following:

```
    if count == 1:
        total =+ 1

print(total)
```

This only gives ' 1 ' when being printed.

I feel kinda dumb asking this question, but it would be nice if someone could give a hint.

Comment: `+=` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
title = ['hello 2017', 'hello 2019', 'bye 2017']
total = 0
for s in title:
    count = s.count('2017')
    total += count
    print(total)
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
```

or

```
title = ['hello 2017', 'hello 2019', 'bye 2017']
total = 0
for s in title:
    count = s.count('2017')
    if count >= 1:
        total += count
        print(total)
    else:
        print(0)
```

Output:

```
1
0
2
```

Comment: Ah, I see.. Let's just forget this question.... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
title = [ hello 2017, hello 2019, bye 2017 ]
for s in title:
    count = s.count('2017')
    print(count)
```

If i understand your question correctly,Yes that's correct and you need to understand that

`i+=1` is the same as `i=i+1`, whereas
`i=+1` just means `i=(+1)`.

[The difference between '+=' and '=+'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643927/the-difference-between-and)

So you have to rewrite your code as :

```py
title = ['hello 2017', 'hello 2019', 'bye 2017']
total = 0
for s in title:
    count = s.count('2017')
    if count == 1:
        total += count
    else:
        print("Count not equals to 1")
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could have totally misunderstood your question but here it goes:

```
import re

title = ['hello 2017', 'hello 2019', 'bye 2017']

for item in title:
    numbers = re.findall(r"(\d)", item)
    total = 0
    for num in numbers:
        try:
            total += int(num)
        except:
            pass
    print(total)
```

output:

```
10
12
10
```

It's added up each of the digits in the years

Answer (score 0):

You can count the occurrences into a list and use `sum()` on it to get the total

```
title = ['hello 2017', 'hello 2019', 'bye 2017']
occurrences = [s.count('2017') for s in title]
print(*occurrences) # 1 0 1, add sep='\n' to print vertically
print(sum(occurrences)) # 2
```