# Nodejs - create an array of files and folders

Tags: javascript

Here's what I'm trying to do, but just can't get my head around...

Say I have the following files and folders in my project, where 'Folder3' is a subfolder of 'Folder2':

```
- Folder1
   - File
   - File
   - File
- Folder2
   - File
   - File
   - File
   - Folder3
      - File
      - File
      - File
```

What I want is create an object that will mirror that structure:

```
var listing = {
   'Folder1' : {
      'File',
      'File',
      'File'
   }
   'Folder2' : {
      'File',
      'File',
      'File',
      'Folder3' : {
         'File',
         'File'
      }
   }
}
```

I've looked at modules such as 'walk', but am not sure how to use them to create an object as described above. I've also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search), but the top answer returns a one dimensional array, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Use the `path` module (https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) and some recursion. Also, take a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search

Comment: @cl3m Saw that question. The answer doesn't quite get what I'm looking for. It returns a one dimensional array. e.g. a file in Folder3 would be described with the string: 'Folder2/Folder3/File'.

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/Cl3MM/1a7aaafe1fdcd43ccd1b You might need to tweak it a little bit.

Comment: by the way, your object structure is not valid. It should look like: `{folder1: [file1, file2, {folder2: [file1, file2, {folder3: [file1]}]}]}`

Answer (score 0):

No dependency (other than node packages itself) working recursive directory traversal:

```js
    var fs = require('fs');
    function readDirs(path, depth) {
        var fileIdentificator = '##file##';
        function readRecursive(pathsObject, path, depthCount) {
            if (depthCount == 0)
                return pathsObject;
            var files = fs.readdirSync(path);
            for (var fileIndex in files) {
                var file = files[fileIndex];
                pathsObject[file] = fileIdentificator;
                var currentPath = path + '/' + file;
                if( fs.lstatSync(currentPath).isDirectory()){
                 readRecursive( pathsObject[file] = {}, currentPath, depthCount-1 );
                }
            }
            return pathsObject;
        }
        return readRecursive({}, path, depth);
    }
    module.exports = readDirs;

//the output will be like this
    {
        a: {
            'a-a': {},
            'a-b': {},
            'a-c': {}
        },
        b: {
            'b-a': {},
            'b-b': {}
        },
        c: {
            'c-file.txt': '##file##'
        },
        d: {
            'd-file.txt': '##file##'
        },
        'root-file.txt': '##file##'
    }
```