# How to list node_modules folders in a json/javascript file?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, npm

I want to introduce the dependencies I have in a d3.js tree and I was wondering if there is any way I can list the dependencies name dynamically in a json file or into the javascript file itself. I don't understand how javascript can read into folder names without external help. I do not wish to use any outside dependencies or server-side javascript.

Comment: It's hard to answer that without any code or any hint about your dependencies structure :/

Comment: @JeremyThille 

...
src/script/myjsfile.js
...
node_modules/     //the folder names I want to read
...
package.json

Comment: I'm willing to help, but you didn't give any information about your code or your dependencies or whatever. So it's a bit hard. `javascript can read into folder names` no, it can't. Javascript doesn't have access to the file system, so again, it's hard to answer you without any info about what you're trying to do.

Comment: You don't want to use any server-side code to read what's in `node_modules` ? :) But NodeJS is pure server-side code... Not sure what's going on here

Comment: @JeremyThille I'm trying to get the node modules folder names and put them into an array. Apologies, I can't share the code.

Comment: Without any server-side code?? Well you just can't do that O_o Client-side javascript has no access to the file system for obvious security reasons. And anyway, the `node_modules` folder is on your server, not on your client.

Comment: How would you do it with server side code?

Comment: simply with the `fs` (File System) module. `fs.readDir("./node_modules")` or something, check out the doc

Comment: but why would you need that anyway? It's precisely `package.json`'s job to hold a list of all your dependencies in one place.

Comment: I want to make a visual representation with a d3 tree.

Comment: Any luck? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search), it might help you. But anyway, forget scanning a directory with client-side JS, it's just not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In your **package.json** you have all the dependencies of your project and each dependency has its own **package.json** at the end there is a **tree of dependencies** that is built,

you can access the package.json with a simple

```
var package = require ('./path/package.json');

console.log(package.devDependencies);
console.log(package.dependencies);
```

i hope i have answered your question :)

Comment: @RuxandraAnghel When you get an error message, then don't paraphrase it but copy it as is. Getting the error "Package is undefined" from the code above is simply not possible.