# How to install npm dependencies which aren't in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have problem with `npm install`. I want to install all dependencies used in my project. In `package.json` there aren't any dependencies, but in my project files I have for example `const mongo=require('mongoose')` and in another file `const morgan=require('morgan')` etc.

I know that when typing `npm i --save <dependency_name>` it will update my `package.json`. But I would like to install all dependencies without typing their names explicitly anywhere.

Is there any way to install all dependencies used in the whole project, but which there aren't in `package.json`?

Comment: Use command `npm i morgan --save`.  This will install dependency and make entry in package.json

Comment: Why are they *not* in the `package.json`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am doing turorial now, and I was thinking about this problem. In this tutorial in  one step there is `install all dependencies`

Comment: What tutorial? What do the instructions on *how* to do that say?

Comment: Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not intended to write your program code first and then let NPM find all dependencies that are used. This is because of a simple reason: Before you can use an external library / package, you'll have to download it, otherwise you could hardly use it at all.

Now, I only see two reasons for your use case:

- you copied and pasted some foreign code where you don't have all files, especially no `package.json`, or
- you "inherited" some code of a former employee or team that is not documented and consists of unrelated, inconsistent files.

---

Anyways, there would be some kinds of solutions for your problem:

1. The nasty solution: Run `npm start` and see what error messages you get. All uninstalled dependencies will not be found, so you'll see the package names and can add them manually to your `package.json`. This will become nasty because you'll have to re-run your program each time. To avoid this, you could have a look at [Nodemon](https://nodemon.io/) which automatically re-starts your program.
2. The better solution: Open a web IDE of your favor and use the "Global Search" function to find all occurrences of the string `require(`, or as a Regex: `require\((.+)\)`. This will list you all dependency imports in your program files. If there should be also ECMA 6 imports, also search for `import (.+) from (.+)`. - However, you'll still have to copy and paste all dependency names from all files manually into your `package.json` file.
3. The best but most complex solution: Write a Node.js script that [scans all your files recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search), beginning in your root project directory. Create a dependency memory variable, like `let dependencies = []`. Read all `*.js` files (sync or async) and every time the `require` or `import` statement is matched, check whether the dependency is already in your `dependencies` array. If not, push it. Finally, all your project dependencies will be listed in the `dependencies` array and you can copy and paste them into your `package.json`.

Pseudo Node.js Code:

```js
const lineReader = require('line-reader');

let dependencies = [];
const regex = /require\(['|"](.+)['|"]\)/g;

lineReader.eachLine('/path/to/file', function(line) {
  const match = regex.exec(line);
  if(match) {
    if(dependencies.indexOf(match[1]) === -1) {
      dependencies.push(match[1]);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that - you will have to add all dependencies by installing them explicitly, like `npm install morgan`. NPM is not aware of the dependencies you're importing in your files. Another thing is that requiring dependencies that are not listed in `package.json` is simply wrong and should never take place.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't

How `npm install` works is checking all your dependencies listed in the `package.json` and install them by once. So either you get the `package.json` from the tutor or you install them one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can scan your project for all required modules.

Assuming your project only uses common.js (require) you can get a list of all modules by doing something like:

```
egrep -R --exclude-dir=node_modules '=\s*require\s*\(' | awk '{gsub(/^.+require\s*\(\s*./,""); gsub(/.\s*\).*$/,""); print $0}'
```

A more readable version of the above command is:

```
#! /bin/bash
egrep -R --exclude-dir=node_modules '=\s*require\s*\(' |
    awk '{
        gsub(/^.+require\s*\(\s*./,"");
        gsub(/.\s*\).*$/,"");
        print $0
    }'
```

You can save the script above in a file and execute it as a shell script.

To automatically install the modules just pipe it to `xargs`:

```
egrep -R --exclude-dir=node_modules '=\s*require\s*\(' |
    awk '{
        gsub(/^.+require\s*\(\s*./,"");
        gsub(/.\s*\).*$/,"");
        print $0
    }' |
    xargs npm install
```

I leave supporting ES6 module as homework for the reader.