# How get a directory structures using Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, directory

Consider these file structures:

```
Parent
├── folder 1
│   └── sub1
│       ├── child a
│       └── sub2
│           ├── btn.xls
│           └── sample.docxs
└── folder 2
    ├── child 1
    └── child 2
        ├── mri.pdf
        ├── lake2.jpg
        └── exp_folder
            ├── exp1.png
            └── exp2.png
```

How can i read this file structures using plain javascript? I am not sure if there is a javascript equivalent of php's `scandir()` function.

Comment: In what environment? A browser? Node.js? Something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in browser. Though i am not so sure if it can be done.

Comment: @Andy - Turns out they want to do this in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You've said you want to do this in a browser. You can't, JavaScript code hosted in the browser in the usual way has no access to the file system. (Some browsers may offer some limited file system access to addons/extensions, but typically only sandboxed access.)