# Accessing images from multiple folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I have the following folder-file structure :

`Main Folder->Subfolder(500 in number)->Each subfolder having 2 to 4 images(jpeg,jpg,png,pdf)`

I want to access all the images via node js all at once. (To the point-> generating a text file which gives me the URL of each image.)

How do I start about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `glob` npm package would help you. Here is an example of how to use it:

File hierarchy:

```
test
├── one.jpg
└── test-nested
    └── two.jpg
```

Your Code

```
var glob = require("glob") 

var getDirectories = function (src, callback) {
  glob(src + '/**/*', callback);
};
getDirectories('test', function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  } else {
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

Which will result in array

```
[ 'test/one.jpg',
  'test/test-nested',
  'test/test-nested/jpg.html' ]
```

You can make changes accordingly.

Comment: it says glob not defined.

Comment: You have to install glob npm

Comment: Here https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob.

Comment: I installed glob npm. I think you need to add the following:   var glob = require("glob")

Comment: Done. Add npm package. Now you can check.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate question and you can find lot of answers here:

The easiest, shortest and most clean one maybe :

[node.js fs.readdir recursive directory search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search)

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = process.cwd()
var files = []

    var getFiles = function(path, files){
        fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(function(file){
            var subpath = path + '/' + file;
            if(fs.lstatSync(subpath).isDirectory()){
                getFiles(subpath, files);
            } else {
                files.push(path + '/' + file);
            }
        });     
    }
```