# How do I count files in a folder in a vscode extension?

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

How do I count files in a folder in a vscode extension and execute it from the context menu in the explorer?

Answer (score 1):

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
const fs = require('fs');

export function walk(dir: string) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search
    // by Victor Powell: https://stackoverflow.com/users/786374/victor-powell
    var results: string[] = [];
    var list = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    list.forEach(function(file: string) {
        file = dir + '/' + file;
        var stat = fs.statSync(file);
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) { 
            // fecurse into a subdirectory
            results = results.concat(walk(file));
        } else { 
            // is a file
            results.push(file);
        }
    });
    return results;
};

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('MMA.countFiles', async (e) => {
        // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed
        let files = walk(e.path);
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`${files.length} files in ${e.path}`);

    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

...and this is the important part in package.json:

```
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "MMA.countFiles",
            "title": "_count.Files"
        }
    ],
    "menus": {
        "explorer/context": [
            {
                "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder",
                "command": "MMA.countFiles",
                "group": "navigation@98"
            }
        ]
    }   
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could do it with [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) pretty easily.  For example

```
const glob = require('glob');

const files = glob.sync('./js/**/*.*', {'nodir': true}); // returns an array of files

console.log(files);
console.log(files.length);
```

where `./js` is the folder in which to recursively count files.  There is also a `dot` option if you have `.files` (dotfiles) to consider.

The recursion, not counting folders, and building the array are all handled for you in one line of code.

Comment: Thanks - I use it in `gulp` quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question.  I did not find an extension for it, but this is how I did it on the command line (Counts the number of files in the `validatorts` folder).

```
ls projects/fs-validatorts/src/lib/validators/ | wc -l
```