# exec() find all files in directory - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, exec

I have got a task where I have a js file where I shall use nodejs and the `exec()` command to list all files in the current directory I am in. I do not know the name of the current directory.
How do I write the `exec()` and ls command in the js file to be able to get a list of the files?

Can anyone in an east way tell me of to write that piece of code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js fs.readdir recursive directory search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search)

Answer (score 3):

That should be fine.
The module 'util' is to promisify exec(), for it to return a promise, then you await it, and can use it.

```
    const util = require('util')
    const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec)
    
    const main = async() => {
            const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('ls', ['a', '-l' ])
            if (stderr) {
                    console.log(stderr)
            }   
            console.log(`the list of files in this directory is: ${stdout}`)
    }
    main()
```

exec (spawn and fork as well) are fork process (child process) from the main node process (mother process), means that they run on a concurrent process, detached from the mother one. It's very efficient as they use another thread of the processor.

In the case of exec, it open a new terminal (tty) and run on it, so the command exec('ls', ['a','-l'}) is running 'ls -l' cmd in a shell (i don t know why the 'a'). Because this exec child-process is running into a shell, any shell command can be executed: I could have done `await exec('find . -type f | wc -l')` return the number of files, or `await exec('cat fileName.js')` (print out the content of fileName in the terminal) return the content of fileName.js into stdout.

Exec return a call-back with (err, stdout, stderr), for this snippet to be more clear, here `util.promisify()` promisify the call-back and then we can use async/await or .then().catch().
We also could have done:

```
const util = require('util')
const { exec } = require('child_process')        
const ex = util.promisify(exec)
const main = async() => {
                const { stdout, stderr } = await ex('ls')
                if (stderr)...
```

In fact more basically this code could be written like this

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('ls', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
          console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

See the nodejs doc https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer! Would you be able to elaborate a bit how this code works :D I am completely new to this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure, see the edit of the previous post.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jerome! That helped a lot and the more basically code where easier for me to understand. :D