# How can I get all the folders inside my current directory and access their data with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, file-manipulation

I have a directory containing a bunch of folders, all having an html,css and js file inside.
I need some way to get like an array of all of these folder in order to access their data and using it in another html file using javascript.
ex:
this is my directory:

```
  currentDirectory>
         folder1>
               htmlFile
               cssFile
               jsFile
         folder2>
               htmlFile
               cssFile
               jsFile
         folder3>
               htmlFile
               cssFile
               jsFile
         etc...
```

I would need to fill up something like this:

```
let foldersInCurrentDirectory = [
                  {
                      RelativePath: '',
                      htmlFileName: '',
                      cssFileName : '',
                      jsFileName  : '',
                      
                   },
                   {
                      RelativePath: '',
                      htmlFileName: '',
                      cssFileName : '',
                      jsFileName  : '',
                      
                   },
                   {
                     //and so on.....
                   }
              ];
```

Comment: Just manual type the name in. You can't do it with plain JS. Maybe node.js would be a better option.

Comment: @TobyHarnish is there a way to like get the data with node and send it to a plain js file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search