# Items not being added to array/map in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have this code which loops through all directories in the folder `commands` and then loops through each file in each of those directories. It then imports the module, converts it to JSON and adds it to an array called `commands` and a map called `client.commands`.

```js
let commands = [];
client.commands = new Map();
fs.readdir(__dirname + "/../commands/", (err, dirs) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    for (let dir of dirs) {
        fs.readdir(__dirname + `/../commands/${dir}/`, (err, files) => {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            for (let file of files) {
                let command = require(`../commands/${dir}/${file}`);
                commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
                client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                console.log(commands);
            }
        });
    }
});
console.log(commands);
```

If I `console.log` the value of `commands` in the inner most for loop, the output is exactly as expected. However, if I log it on the outside of the entire code block, it just prints an empty list.

Comment: One word: Asynchronous

Comment: Two words: Use `readdirSync()`

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'd suggest using promises. Node `fs` module has builtin APIs for promises. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

Comment: @RandyCasburn  generally speaking it's best avoided.  Might be ok for simple console functions, but if you do that in a multi-user web server for example it's not a great idea.

Comment: @undefined There is nothing diabolical or evil or terrible about doing work synchronously. There are actually use cases in which it is desired. Bottom line - it is a viable solution that works. The OP can choose.

Comment: @Keith - This is a file reader that does data transformation. The use case is plain to see. Nothing wrong with sync here.

Comment: @RandyCasburn  There is nothing in the OP's code to suggest this couldn't be used in say an express app.  And if it was, it going to block requests.  And I did say, might be OK for simple console apps.

Comment: @Keith and there is nothing that says that it is - as I said, the OP can choose.

Comment: @RandyCasburn  Then why make an assumption, if the OP uses promises, we don't even need to make that distinction.  Not sure why your getting umpty about it, especially as I put a proviso that it's maybe OK for simple console apps.

Comment: I think DerEchteKroate has the point on this. Looks like Discord. If so, Op should tag question as such.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use recursion to read the files inside the folders recursively.
And below link the question that already asked I think will help to solve this.
[Node.js fs.readdir recursive directory search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like discord.js to me.

```js
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`.commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

Your commands should look like this

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "name",
    description: "description",
    execute() {
    // execution code
    }
}
```

You can then use it by calling the function or getting the variables

```js
client.commands.get(/* Name of command */).execute();
```

Comment: Nice Catch. Should likely have the discord tag on the question if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

since readdir() is asynchrose, your outer console.log() is called before the function in the middle is fully executed.

I adjusted the syntax to the more modern async and await since fallback functions are not the best Practice anymore, unfortunately I couldn't test it, but it is atleast the correct way to go ;)

```js
let commands = [];
client.commands = new Map();

async function main() {
    try {
        const dirs = await fs.readdir(__dirname + "/../commands/")
        for (let dir of dirs) {
            const files = await fs.readdir(__dirname + `/../commands/${dir}/`)
            for (let file of files) {
                let command = require(`../commands/${dir}/${file}`);
                commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
                client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                console.log(commands);
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(err)
    }

    console.log(commands);
}

main()
```