# Dynamic Grid Menu for Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im not actually sure if the title is correct, but I am unsure what to call it.

I am looking for a way to create a dynamic menu within my website. I am looking to create folders in my "djscimmia.com/gig-log" directory and have my website create a new grid item accordingly.

For each new grid item, when selected through "www.djscimmia.com/gig-log", I want to proceed to that folder and display another grid displaying the images and videos within that subfolder.

So in basic, I want to go from:

www.djscimmia.com/gig-log (with grid layout of subfolders)

To:

www.djscimmia.com/gig-log/*Whatever the folder is called*

With a gallery inside the page.

So what I am looking for is a way to create a dynamic grid menu for both subfolders that can be identified when a new folder is created in my main folder, and a way to create the same looking grid display as a gallery for the subfolders images and videos?

Any help or links to help would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are accessing files/directories, its better to use server-side scripting languages. These links may help.

[How can I create a simple index.html file which lists all files/directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785055/how-can-i-create-a-simple-index-html-file-which-lists-all-files-directories)

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/display-styled-directory-contents/

Comment: You sir are a legend! I should be able to setup something using those links. Thank you heaps!

Comment: How would I make it that each link available in my index has a "download" attribute?

    <a href="/files/image_1.png" download="img.png">Download Your Image</a>

Comment: I dont follow what you mean. Referring to second link?